# PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher in Android 4.x

Tags: android

I have the following code that was working fine in Android 2.2 to format phone numbers by 555-555-5555, but in 4.x it is formatting them in 555555-555.

```
inputPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPhoneNumber);
inputPhoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like there have been some changes in source: [1.5](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.java) and [4.0.4](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.java)

Answer (score 0):

There is another android class specially for formatting phone number [PhoneNumberUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html)

and some methods you can use:

- **formatNumber(String source)** Breaks the given number down and formats
  it according to the rules for the country the number is from.
- **formatNumber(Editable text, int defaultFormattingType)** Formats a
  phone number in-place.

Chect it out.

Comment: Thanks! I will review those, but I found out my error in case it helps anyone in the future: In my xml I had not allowed "(" or ")" as digits, and phonenumberformattingtextwatcher formats the phone as (555)555-5555 in 4.x as opposed to 555-555-5555.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @learningslowly helped, but I found it to be still incomplete. The full allowed digits string needed for correct & 'normal' format is:

`android:digits="0123456789()-+ "`

I was previously missing the minus, plus, and space.